# I have payments data and I need suggestions from experts what can I do

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have data for a local payment service that is not compatible with standards for electronic payment services such as Visa cards.

The service depends on sending a message to the buyer from the merchant containing the cost value then the buyer confirms the process

Unfortunately there is not much useful information nor details about the customers such as  age or location, but I have some fields such as **payment value**, and **time of begin transaction** and **time of end transaction** and merchant & customer **account number** and **type of process** (Buy, Retrieve), also **Point of Sell Number**.

I thought about classifying these transactions using k-means algorithm but ..
What can I get insights from these data, Do i can detect the anomalies in them based on time and value only and the rest of the fields mentioned above?